# How to set circularReferenceLimit in SerializerInterface Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, serialization

I have an error

> A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of
>   class "AppBundle\Entity\Match" (configured limit: 1) This is because I
>   try to serialize entity class with references

. So far I discovered i need to execute $normalizer->setCircularReferenceLimit(2);
How do i do this with SerializerInterface.

My code is

```
/**
 * @Route("/v2/json/match/{id}", name="json_single_match")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function getSingleMatchAction(SerializerInterface $serializer, $id) {

    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Match');
    $post = $repo->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    $data = $serializer->serialize(['post' => $post], 'json', ['groups' => ["rest", "matches", "players"]]);
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setContent($data);
    return $response;

}


get_set_method_normalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer
    public: false
    tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could specify the maxDepth in your entity with annotations, will that work for you ?

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

namespace Acme;

class MyObj
{
    /**
     * @MaxDepth(2)
     */
    public $child;

    // ...
 }
```